# Corruption of UBI in UBIFS

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ubifs

We are using Linux-2.6.28 and 2 Gb NAND Flash in our system ; After some amount of power cycle tests we are observing the following errors :

```
Volume operational found at volume id 3
read 21966848 bytes from volume 3 to 80400000(buf address)
UBI error: ubi_io_read: error -77 while reading 126976 bytes from PEB 1074:4096, read    126976 bytes
UBI: force data checking
UBI error: ubi_io_read: error -77 while reading 126976 bytes from PEB 1074:4096, read 126976 bytes
UBI warning: ubi_eba_read_leb: CRC error: calculated 0xa7cab743, must be 0x15716fce
read err ffffffb3
```

These errors are not hardware errors as if we remove the offending partition, we are able to boot the hardware fine; Maybe UBIFS is not correcting the bad UBI block.

Any UBI patches have been added in the latest kernels to address this issue ? Thanks.

Comment: Is your NAND MLC?  UBI/UbiFS assume that when power is cut a journal is written in order.  So if it writing A,B,C,D and part B has an issue, it looks at C to see if it is erased.  If it is not, then it assumes that B was corrupt and it gives up on the filesystem.  With MLC, a write to one page can affect another.  Your issue maybe hardware; you can not use MLC flash.  There are other issues which can occur.  2.6.28 is ancient and there are many fixes to UBI/UbiFS. Also [unstable bits](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/ubifs.html#L_unstable_bits).  Finally, the MTD driver can be the issue.

Comment: Thanks. NAND device in our case is SLC ; in addition to power cut failures we do see UBIFS failures while doing continous writes. We wrote a small script which will write into the file system continously and we see the above failures. Any thought ?

Comment: +1 for testing your filesystem.  I made an answer of sorts for you.

Answer (score 6):

The error printed is a **UBI** error.  Lets look at [the source](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/mtd/ubi/io.c?id=v2.6.28#n134) near line 177,

```
ubi_err("error %d while reading %d bytes from PEB %d:%d, "
    "read %zd bytes", err, len, pnum, offset, read);
```

So, error '-77' (normally -EBADFD) was returned from the NAND flash driver when trying to read the 'physical erase block' #1074 at offset 4096 (2nd page for 2k pages).  UBI include volume management pages which are typically located at the beginning of a *physical erase block* (PEB for short).

Note that the [latest mainline of *io.c*](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/mtd/ubi/io.c#n143) has the following comment and code,

```
/*
 * Deliberately corrupt the buffer to improve robustness. Indeed, if we
 * do not do this, the following may happen:
 * 1. The buffer contains data from previous operation, e.g., read from
 *    another PEB previously. The data looks like expected, e.g., if we
 *    just do not read anything and return - the caller would not
 *    notice this. E.g., if we are reading a VID header, the buffer may
 *    contain a valid VID header from another PEB.
 * 2. The driver is buggy and returns us success or -EBADMSG or
 *    -EUCLEAN, but it does not actually put any data to the buffer.
 *
 * This may confuse UBI or upper layers - they may think the buffer
 * contains valid data while in fact it is just old data. This is
 * especially possible because UBI (and UBIFS) relies on CRC, and
 * treats data as correct even in case of ECC errors if the CRC is
 * correct.
 *
 * Try to prevent this situation by changing the first byte of the
 * buffer.
 */
*((uint8_t *)buf) ^= 0xFF;
```

The following code can be used to process a UBI/UbiFS dump and look for abnormalities,

```
/* -*- mode: c; compile-command: "gcc -Wall -g -o parse_ubi parse_ubi.c"; -*- */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <endian.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define __packed __attribute__((packed))
#include "ubi-media.h"

#define bswap16 be16toh
#define bswap32 be32toh
#define bswap64 be64toh

static int dump_vid = 0;

#define CRCPOLY_LE 0xedb88320
static unsigned int crc32(unsigned int crc, void const *_p, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char const *p = _p;
    int i;
    while (len--) {
        crc ^= *p++;
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ ((crc & 1) ? CRCPOLY_LE : 0);
    }
    return crc;
}

#define ALEN(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))
static void print_ec(struct ubi_ec_hdr *ec)
{
    if(ec->version != UBI_VERSION || ec->magic != UBI_EC_HDR_MAGIC) {
        printf(" Magic: %x\n", ec->magic);
        printf(" Version: %d\n", (int)ec->version);
        printf(" EC: %llx\n", ec->ec);
        printf(" VID offset: %x\n", ec->vid_hdr_offset);
        printf(" Data offset: %x\n", ec->data_offset);
        printf(" Image seq: %x\n", ec->image_seq);
        exit(-1);
    }
}

static void read_ec(int fd, struct ubi_ec_hdr *ec)
{
    int rval = read(fd, ec,sizeof(*ec));
    if(rval == sizeof(*ec)) {
        unsigned int crc;
        crc = crc32(UBI_CRC32_INIT, ec, UBI_EC_HDR_SIZE_CRC);
        ec->magic = bswap32(ec->magic);
        ec->vid_hdr_offset = bswap32(ec->vid_hdr_offset);
        ec->data_offset = bswap32(ec->data_offset);
        ec->image_seq = bswap32(ec->image_seq);
        ec->hdr_crc = bswap32(ec->hdr_crc);
        ec->ec = bswap64(ec->ec);
        if(crc != ec->hdr_crc)
            printf("EC CRC: %x/%x\n", crc, ec->hdr_crc);
    } else
        memset(ec, 0, sizeof(*ec));
}

static void print_vid(int vid_num, struct ubi_vid_hdr *vid)
{
    if(vid->magic != UBI_VID_HDR_MAGIC)
        printf(" Magic: %x\n", vid->magic);
    if(vid->version != UBI_VERSION)
        printf(" Version: %d\n", (int)vid->version);

    if(!dump_vid) return;

    printf("VID %d\n", vid_num);

    /* This is usually the same. */
    if(vid->vol_id >= UBI_INTERNAL_VOL_START)
        printf("Internal vol_id: %d\n", vid->vol_id - UBI_INTERNAL_VOL_START);
    if(vid->vol_type != UBI_VID_DYNAMIC)
        printf(" vol_type: %s\n",
               vid->vol_type == UBI_VID_DYNAMIC ? "dynamic" : "static");
    if(vid->used_ebs)
        printf(" used_ebs: %d\n", vid->used_ebs);
    if(vid->data_pad)
        printf(" data_pad: %d\n", vid->data_pad);
    if((vid->copy_flag != 1 && vid->data_size) ||
       (vid->copy_flag == 0 && vid->data_size))
        printf(" copy_flag: %d\n", (int)vid->copy_flag);

    printf(" lnum: %d\n", vid->lnum);
    if(vid->compat) {
        const char *compat[] = {
            [UBI_COMPAT_DELETE]   = "delete",
            [UBI_COMPAT_RO]       = "ro",
            [UBI_COMPAT_PRESERVE] = "preserve",
            [UBI_COMPAT_REJECT]   = "reject"
        };
        printf(" compat: %s\n", compat[vid->compat]);
    }
    printf(" data_size: %d\n", vid->data_size);
    /* printf(" data_crc: %x\n", vid->data_crc); */
    printf(" hdr_crc: %x\n", vid->hdr_crc);
    printf(" sqnum: %lld\n", vid->sqnum);
}

static int read_vid(int fd, struct ubi_vid_hdr *vid)
{
    int rval = read(fd, vid,sizeof(*vid));
    if(rval == sizeof(*vid)) {
        unsigned int crc;
        crc = crc32(UBI_CRC32_INIT, vid, UBI_EC_HDR_SIZE_CRC);
        vid->magic = bswap32(vid->magic);
        vid->vol_id = bswap32(vid->vol_id);
        vid->lnum = bswap32(vid->lnum);
        vid->data_size = bswap32(vid->data_size);
        vid->used_ebs = bswap32(vid->used_ebs);
        vid->data_pad = bswap32(vid->data_pad);
        vid->data_crc = bswap32(vid->data_crc);
        vid->hdr_crc = bswap32(vid->hdr_crc);
        vid->sqnum = bswap64(vid->sqnum);
        if(crc != vid->hdr_crc && vid->magic == UBI_VID_HDR_MAGIC)
            printf("VID CRC: %x/%x\n", crc, vid->hdr_crc);
    } else
        memset(vid, 0, sizeof(*vid));
    return rval;
}

static void print_vtbl(struct ubi_vtbl_record *vtbl)
{
    printf(" Found vtbl [%d] %s\n", vtbl->name_len, vtbl->name);
    printf(" Reserved PEBs: %d\n", vtbl->reserved_pebs);
    printf(" Align: %d\n", vtbl->alignment);
    printf(" Pad: %d\n", vtbl->data_pad);
    if(vtbl->vol_type != UBI_VID_DYNAMIC)
        printf(" vol_type: %s\n",
               vtbl->vol_type == UBI_VID_DYNAMIC ? "dynamic" : "static");
    printf(" Update: %d\n", vtbl->upd_marker);
    printf(" Flags: %d\n", (int)vtbl->flags);
}

static void read_vtbl(int fd, struct ubi_vtbl_record *vtbl)
{
    int rval = read(fd, vtbl, sizeof(*vtbl));
    if(rval == sizeof(*vtbl)) {
        vtbl->reserved_pebs = bswap32(vtbl->reserved_pebs);
        vtbl->alignment = bswap32(vtbl->alignment);
        vtbl->data_pad = bswap32(vtbl->data_pad);
        vtbl->crc = bswap32(vtbl->crc);
        vtbl->name_len = bswap16(vtbl->name_len);
    } else
        memset(vtbl, 0, sizeof(*vtbl));
}

static void print_fm_sb(struct ubi_fm_sb *fm_sb)
{
    int i;

    if(fm_sb->magic != UBI_FM_SB_MAGIC)
        printf(" Magic: %x\n", fm_sb->magic);
    if(fm_sb->version != UBI_VERSION)
        printf(" Version: %d\n", (int)fm_sb->version);
    printf(" data_crc: %x\n", fm_sb->data_crc);
    printf(" used_blocks: %x\n", fm_sb->used_blocks);
    for(i = 0; i < fm_sb->used_blocks; i++)
        printf(" block_loc[%d]: %d\n", i, fm_sb->block_loc[i]);
    for(i=0; i < fm_sb->used_blocks; i++)
        printf(" block_ec[%d]: %d\n", i, fm_sb->block_ec[i]);
    printf(" sqnum: %lld\n", fm_sb->sqnum);
}

static void read_fm_sb(int fd, struct ubi_fm_sb *fm_sb)
{
    int rval = read(fd, fm_sb, sizeof(*fm_sb));
    if(rval == sizeof(*fm_sb)) {
        int i;
        fm_sb->magic = bswap32(fm_sb->magic);
        fm_sb->data_crc = bswap32(fm_sb->data_crc);
        fm_sb->used_blocks = bswap32(fm_sb->used_blocks);
        for(i=0; i < UBI_FM_MAX_BLOCKS; i++)
            fm_sb->block_loc[i] = bswap32(fm_sb->block_loc[i]);
        for(i=0; i < UBI_FM_MAX_BLOCKS; i++)
            fm_sb->block_ec[i] = bswap32(fm_sb->block_ec[i]);
        fm_sb->sqnum = bswap64(fm_sb->sqnum);
    } else
        memset(fm_sb, 0, sizeof(*fm_sb));
}

/* Set logical block at physical. */
static int eba_map[1920];
static int pba_map[1920];

static void usage(char *name)
{
    printf("Usage: %s -b [erase block size] -e -v <ubi file> \n", name);
    printf("Where,\n -e  is dump the logic to physical block map.\n");
    printf(" -v  is dump the VID headers.\n");
    printf(" -b [size] sets the erase block size (flash dependent).\n");

}

typedef struct fastmap {
    struct ubi_fm_sb        fm_sb;
    struct ubi_fm_hdr       hdr;
    struct ubi_fm_scan_pool pool1;
    struct ubi_fm_scan_pool pool2;
    /* Free, Used, Scrub and Erase */
    struct ubi_fm_ec        ec[0];
    /* ... */
    /* struct ubi_fm_volhdr vol; */
    /* struct ubi_fm_eba eba[0]; */

} fastmap;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd, i, erase_block = 0, eba_flag = 0;
    int c;
    struct ubi_ec_hdr ec;
    struct ubi_vid_hdr vid;
    int erase_size = 0x20000;
    int leb_size;
    off_t cur_ec = 0;
    int vidless_blocks = 0;

    while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "hveb:")) != -1)
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'h': /* Help */
                usage(argv[0]);
                goto out;
            case 'b':
                erase_size = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 'e':
                eba_flag = 1;
                break;
            case 'v':
                dump_vid = 1;
                break;
            case '?':
                if (optopt == 'b')
                    fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
                else if (isprint (optopt))
                    fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
                else
                    fprintf (stderr,
                             "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                             optopt);
                return 1;
            default:
                goto out;
        }

    if(optind >= argc) {
        usage(argv[0]);
        goto out;
    }

    fd = open(argv[optind], O_RDONLY);
    if(fd < 0) {
        printf("Bad file: %s\n", argv[1]);
        goto out;
    }

    memset(eba_map, -1, sizeof(eba_map));
    memset(pba_map, -1, sizeof(pba_map));

    /* Process each 'erase block'. */
    read_ec(fd,&ec);
    while(ec.magic == UBI_EC_HDR_MAGIC) {
        leb_size = erase_size - ec.data_offset;
        print_ec(&ec);

        /* VID present? */
        if(lseek(fd, ec.vid_hdr_offset-sizeof(ec), SEEK_CUR) == -1) {
            printf("Seek error: %s\n", argv[1]);
            goto out;
        }

        if(read_vid(fd,&vid) != sizeof(vid)) {
            printf("File too small: %s\n", argv[1]);
            goto out;
        }
        if(vid.magic == UBI_VID_HDR_MAGIC) {
            print_vid(erase_block, &vid);
            if(vid.vol_id == 3) {
                if(eba_map[vid.lnum] != -1)
                    printf("EBA dup: %d %d\n", eba_map[vid.lnum], erase_block);
                eba_map[vid.lnum] = erase_block;
            }
            pba_map[erase_block] = vid.lnum;

            /* Read volume table. */
            if(vid.vol_id == UBI_INTERNAL_VOL_START) {
                /* Seek to PEB data offset. */
                if(lseek(fd,
                         ec.data_offset - ec.vid_hdr_offset - sizeof(vid),
                         SEEK_CUR) == -1)
                    printf("Seek error: %s\n", argv[1]);
                else {
                    int i;
                    struct ubi_vtbl_record vtbl;
                    for(i = 0; i < UBI_MAX_VOLUMES; i++) {
                        read_vtbl(fd, &vtbl);
                        if(vtbl.reserved_pebs ||
                           vtbl.name_len ||
                           strcmp((char*)vtbl.name, "") != 0) {
                            printf("VTBL %d\n", i);
                            print_vtbl(&vtbl);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if(vid.vol_id == UBI_FM_SB_VOLUME_ID) {
                printf("Found Fastmap super block @PEB %d.\n", erase_block);
                if(lseek(fd,
                         ec.data_offset - ec.vid_hdr_offset - sizeof(vid),
                         SEEK_CUR) == -1)
                    printf("Seek error: %s\n", argv[1]);
                else {
                    void *data = alloca(leb_size);
                    struct ubi_fm_sb *fm_sb = data;
                    read_fm_sb(fd, data);
                    print_fm_sb(fm_sb);
                }
            } else if(vid.vol_id == UBI_FM_DATA_VOLUME_ID) {
                printf("Found Fastmap data block @PEB %d.\n", erase_block);
                printf("UNSUPPORTED!!!\n");
            }

        } else if(vid.magic != 0xffffffff){
            printf("VID %d corrupt! %x\n", erase_block, vid.magic);
        } else {
            vidless_blocks++;
        }

        erase_block++;
        cur_ec += erase_size;
        cur_ec = lseek(fd, cur_ec, SEEK_SET);

        /* Process Erase counter. */
        read_ec(fd,&ec);
    }

    printf("Found %d vidless (free) blocks.\n", vidless_blocks);
    if(eba_flag) {
        printf("Logical to physical.\n");
        for(i = 0; i < ALEN(eba_map); i+=8)
            printf("%4d: %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d"
                   " %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d\n", i,
                   eba_map[i],   eba_map[i+1],
                   eba_map[i+2], eba_map[i+3],
                   eba_map[i+4], eba_map[i+5],
                   eba_map[i+6], eba_map[i+7],
                   eba_map[i+8], eba_map[i+9],
                   eba_map[i+10], eba_map[i+11],
                   eba_map[i+12], eba_map[i+13],
                   eba_map[i+14], eba_map[i+15]);
        printf("Physical to logical.\n");
        for(i = 0; i < ALEN(pba_map); i+=8)
            printf("%4d: %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d"
                   " %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d %4d\n", i,
                   pba_map[i],   pba_map[i+1],
                   pba_map[i+2], pba_map[i+3],
                   pba_map[i+4], pba_map[i+5],
                   pba_map[i+6], pba_map[i+7],
                   pba_map[i+8], pba_map[i+9],
                   pba_map[i+10], pba_map[i+11],
                   pba_map[i+12], pba_map[i+13],
                   pba_map[i+14], pba_map[i+15]);
    }
out:
    return 0;
}
```

To build copy *ubi-media.h* from the UBI directory and run `gcc -Wall -g -o parse_ubi parse_ubi.c`.  The code probably has issues on big-endian platforms; it is also not test with 2.6.28 but I believe it should work as the UBI structures shouldn't change.  You may have to remove some *fastmap* code, if it doesn't compile. The code should give some indication on what is wrong with PEB#1074.  Make a copy of the partition when failing and use the code above to analyze the UBI layer.

It is quite possible that the MTD driver does something abnormal which prevents UBI from attaching to an MTD partition.  This in-turn prevents UbiFS from mounting.  If you know what MTD Nand flash controller is being used, it would help others determine where the issue is.

It can be caused by MTD bugs and/or hardware bugs or UBI/UbiFS issues. If it is UBI/UbiFs, there are [backport trees](http://git.infradead.org/users/dedekind/ubifs-v2.6.32.git) and [newer 3.0](http://git.infradead.org/users/dedekind/ubifs-v3.0.git). You can try to steal the patches from 2.6.32; after applying all, add the 3.0.

Again, the issue can be the MTD driver.  Grab MTD changes for your particular CPU/SOCs NAND flash controller. I do this from the mainline; some changes are bug fixes and others infra-structure. You have to look at each patch individually

Comment: If the *parse_ubi* finds something wrong before PEB#1074, then it maybe the NAND flash driver buffer issue noted in the current mainline source.